# Windows Service: Get processes for all users, including MainWindowHandle

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, service, process

I have written a Windows Service in PowerShell. It works well, but there is one major limitation that I need to find a solution for. I need to list all processes with **Windowed** Applications - this is for passive application metering (I.E. Apps opened and in-use by each logged-on user).

The service runs as `Local System`. I can see all of the processes, but as the service is in the non-interactive desktop (Session ID 0) I cannot see the MainWindowTitle or MainWindowhandle, the titles are all null and the handles are all 0.

I have tried using `Get-Process`, `Get-CIMInstance Win32_Process` and `[System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetProcesses()`. None of these worked (I get all processes, but with data redacted).

I decided to create a C# console application that the PowerShell service will execute and collect the response from. This worked, but still excluded 'sensitive' information, so the critical property `MainWindowhandle` was always 0.

Here is the C# console app (it was a quick job to test only):

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Permissions;

namespace ProcessManager
{

    public class ProcessRecord
    {
        // Auto-Initialized properties  
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int MainWindowHandle { get; set; }
        public string WindowTitle { get; set; }
        public int SessionId { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        [PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Name = "FullTrust")]
        [HostProtectionAttribute(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, SharedState = true, Synchronization = true, ExternalProcessMgmt = true, SelfAffectingProcessMgmt = true)]
        [PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.InheritanceDemand, Name = "FullTrust")]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            listProcesses();
        }

        public static void listProcesses()
        {
            List<ProcessRecord> processesList = new List<ProcessRecord>{};
            Process.GetProcesses().ToList().ForEach(p =>
            {
                try 
                {
                    processesList.Add(new ProcessRecord
                    {
                        Name = p.ProcessName,
                        MainWindowHandle = (int) p.MainWindowHandle,
                        WindowTitle = p.MainWindowTitle,
                        SessionId = p.SessionId,
                        StartTime = p.StartTime
                    });
                }
                catch (Win32Exception)
                {
                    // Just ignoring this to avoid the Access Denied exception for low-level system processes
                }
                
            });
            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(processesList));
        }
    }
}
```

I tried running the service as a Local User in the local Administrators group. I also tried enabling 'Allow the service to interact with the desktop' out of desperation.

**I do not need to know the MainWindowHandle**, I just need to list processes where the MainWindowhandle is not 0. Unfortunately, I will need to know the session ID.

How should I proceed? Is the answer simple **"It cannot be done"** or is there a naughty workaround, such as impersonation?

Maybe there's an easier way to list applications opened by users without having to depend on `MainWindowHandle != 0`?

Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: Thanks @vad, but the issue is that I'm running this as a service in the non-interactive desktop. `Get-process` will return `mainwindowhandle` as 0 for all processes, as the property in unreadable for security reasons.

Comment: So, you are trying to find all non-interactive processes, not specifically for your tool? If it was just for your tool, during the create, trap for the info there. There still should be 'StartInfo' for any process on the machines. --- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.environment?view=netframework-4.8 --- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getuserobjectinformationa?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: I can only imagine, I appreciate the guidance!

Answer (score 0):

If you need process with Windowed Applications you can filter process by property `mainwindowhandle`

```
Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.mainwindowhandle -ne 0} | select ProcessName | ft -HideTableHeaders
```

Comment: Thanks @vad, this was the first thing I tried. The issue is that I'm running this as a service in the non-interactive desktop. Get-process will return mainwindowhandle as 0 for all processes, as the property in unreadable for security reasons. I did make this clear in the question?